# How to pause code execution while waiting for UIAlertView response?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have UIAlertView and I need to decide which code to run according to the user response (depends on the button the user presses YES/NO) I've found some solutions for that but they all won't work for me:

To put the rest of the code in the

```
-(void)alertView : (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex : (NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

function but the thing is that my alert doesn't run on every execution but only on certain occasions so I need the code in the original function which makes this solution impossible for me.

To use a flag (clicked) which indicates that the button was pressed and to use the following line of code:

```
while (!clicked) [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

but when I use it I can't press the buttons on the UIAlert, I mean, it would not respond.
Then I've found a bit different solution that someone claimed that it works for him, the original code was in c# but in obj-c it would be:

```
while (!clicked) [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0.5]];
```

but in this case also I  get the same response problems.

Please help me make one of this solutions work or suggest another one.

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

the first case delegate of alertview is the easiest way

```
if(showalert==true)//there will be a case to show alert or not 
{
show alert implement rest of code in delegate
}
else
{
write the rest of code here, if alertview is not called it will execute
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not good enough for me because within this code i have to do some changes of variables which are private variables of the original function and I dont want to make them global.